Filebeat creates indexes that do not respect the index_template mapping
I have an issue with filebeat where I have configured an index_template and its mapping but the indices created in the filebeat do not follow the mapping of the index_template.
filebeat version is 7.17.22
filebeat.yml
setup.dashboards.enabled: false
setup.ilm.enabled: true
setup.ilm.pattern: '{now/d}-000001'
setup.ilm.policy_name: 1d_rollover_90d_coldstorage_365d_delete
setup.ilm.rollover_alias: filebeat-logs-ov2-staging-microservices
setup.template.enabled: true
setup.template.name: filebeat-logs-ov2-staging-microservices
setup.template.pattern: filebeat-logs-ov2-staging-microservices-*
setup.template.settings:
  index.lifecycle.name: 1d_rollover_90d_coldstorage_365d_delete
  index.lifecycle.rollover_alias: filebeat-logs-ov2-staging-microservices

my index template has the following mapping
{
  "properties": {
    "geoip": {
      "properties": {
        "location": {
          "type": "geo_point"
        }
      }
    },
    "pm2_env": {
      "properties": {
        "axm_monitor": {
          "properties": {
            "Event Loop Latency": {
              "properties": {
                "value": {
                  "type": "double"
                }
              }
            },
            "Used Heap Size": {
              "properties": {
                "value": {
                  "type": "double"
                }
              }
            },
            "Event Loop Latency p95": {
              "properties": {
                "value": {
                  "type": "double"
                }
              }
            },
            "Heap Size": {
              "properties": {
                "value": {
                  "type": "double"
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "responseSize": {
      "type": "double"
    },
    "processingTime": {
      "type": "double"
    }
  }
}

and my indexes created by filebeat look like this
   "Event Loop Latency": {
                  "properties": {
                    "historic": {
                      "type": "boolean"
                    },
                    "type": {
                      "type": "text",
                      "fields": {
                        "keyword": {
                          "type": "keyword",
                          "ignore_above": 256
                        }
                      }
                    },
                    "unit": {
                      "type": "text",
                      "fields": {
                        "keyword": {
                          "type": "keyword",
                          "ignore_above": 256
                        }
                      }
                    },
                    "value": {
                      "type": "text",
                      "fields": {
                        "keyword": {
                          "type": "keyword",
                          "ignore_above": 256
                        }
                      }
                    }
                  }
                },


why isn't the value the type double as per the index template?

Let's focus on a single field to diagnose the issue. pm2_env.axm_monitor.Event Loop Latency.value field type defined as double in the index template but it's indexed as keyword. Create a test index and let's check the mapping PUT filebeat-logs-ov2-staging-microservices-test and check the field type GET *-test/_mapping/field/pm2_env.axm_monitor.Event Loop Latency.value

I have tried this GET *-test/_mapping/field/pm2_env.axm_monitor.Event Loop Latency.value but it always throws an error "reason": "request [GET /filebeat-logs-ov2-staging-microservices-test/_mapping/field/pm2_env.axm_monitor.Event] does not support having a body"
but when I check the mapping of the new index using GET filebeat-logs-ov2-staging-microservices-test/_mapping I cannot see the correct mapping {   "filebeat-logs-ov2-staging-microservices-test": {     "mappings": {}   } }

thanks for sharing. The empty body means none of the index templates matched with the index_name. Create the index template first and try again.
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-templates-v1.html
